# How to add more bars to this Animated JQuery, CSS and HTML Bar Graph

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to use the [graph explained in this website](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/23/create-an-animated-bar-graph-with-html-css-and-jquery/) in my web application. I want to use it to show some monthly statistics for each division in my company. So in the legend I could be able to list the divisions names (I have 7 divisions). Now I want to create 7 bars in the graph, but I have not been able to do that. Could anyone tell me how to add more bars to the graph?

My HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
        <title>Example 3 - Animated Bar Chart via jQuery</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/03.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="toggles">
            <p><a href="#" id="reset-graph-button">Reset graph</a>
            Mouse over the bars to display information.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="chart">
                <h2>PMOD Divisions' Safety Training Record</h2>

                <table id="data-table" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" summary="The effects of the zombie outbreak on the populations of endangered species from 2012 to 2016">
                    <caption>Population in thousands</caption>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <th scope="col">September</th>
                            <th scope="col">October</th>
                            <th scope="col">November</th>
                            <th scope="col">December</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>

                            <th scope="row">A</th>
                            <td>4080</td>
                            <td>6080</td>
                            <td>6240</td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">E</th>
                            <td>5680</td>
                            <td>6880</td>
                            <td>5760</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">D</th>
                            <td>1040</td>
                            <td>1760</td>
                            <td>2880</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">PE</th>
                            <td>5680</td>
                            <td>6880</td>
                            <td>5760</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">OD</th>
                            <td>5680</td>
                            <td>6880</td>
                            <td>5760</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">ES</th>
                            <td>5680</td>
                            <td>6770</td>
                            <td>5760</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">SS</th>
                            <td>5680</td>
                            <td>6880</td>
                            <td>5760</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- JavaScript at the bottom for fast page loading -->


        <!-- Grab jQuery from Google -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Example JavaScript -->
        <script src="js/03.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add an extra rows to the table, like you did.

What rest is CSS styling. You need to refine the width attribute of a couple classes: legend, x-axis and so on.

You also need to define fig-classes for each bar, see .fig0 .fig1 and so on.

See 03.css: http://provide.smashingmagazine.com/graph_tut_files/css/03.css

See common.css: http://provide.smashingmagazine.com/graph_tut_files/css/common.css